# Hosting WCF service and static html files

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf, html, rest

We are developing an application which has static html pages + jquery on the client side. The client gets data from a rest-ful WCF service which will be ultimately hosted in IIS.

I'm bit confused on how to structure it in VS/host it.One of the pre requisite is that I'm not allowed to put the client side html static content into an asp.net app just for the sake of it.

My aim is the following:
- Have a mechanism where the client dev and the service dev can integrate there work easily, i.e on running a single project they should be seeing there progress of there work.
- Separate client and service projects are allowed, however the client cannot be hosted in an asp.net app.
- Within my client code, I should be able to retrieve data relatively from the service uri's. i.e I should not be tied down to a specific port or localhost, but if i say `/getmydata` from the WCF serivce, rather than `http://localhost:51345/getmydata`, it should return data from the service.

For the service side, I'm using a route table instead of an svc file.

Right now, the thinking is to bundle the service and the client static content into a single host project and query data relatively.My question is - is there a better approach to do this? Also should I be taking care of any security issues while doing this/or while hosting it in iis/my development server?

Comment: https://delog.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/serving-static-web-content-using-wcf/

Comment: I'd be real careful with @imagine's suggestion. Seems for an attacker to provide a URL to content like "../../../important.doc" and get access to files they shouldn't.

Comment: jm., you are right, this code needs some changes, I meant the idea...